# Should I use PreserveSigAttribute or MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, custom-attributes

If I wanted to set the `preservesig` method impl flag on a method, should I use [`PreserveSigAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.preservesigattribute.aspx) or [`MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx)? They both seem to do the same thing. Which should I use?